# How to launch a terminal which executes vim from a script?

Tags: terminal

Basically, what I want to achieve is something similar to `gnome-terminal -e vim` in Linux.

It will launch a `vim` window and when I quit `vim` with `:q`, the window will be closed.

How can I do this with Terminal?

Comment: Let me give you an up-vote, since two found it clear enough to answer but forgot to up vote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a wrapper script for `vim`:

```
#! /bin/ksh
#
# vimwrapper
#
#
/usr/bin/vim
```

Make the script executable- `chmod 755 vimwrapper` and call the script like this

```
open -a Terminal.app vimwrapper
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip. I never knew I can execute a command directly without passing any options. The only problem I met with this approach is when I do `:q` to quit it. The terminal window can not be closed. I have to close it manually by mouse. I just want to avoid any mouse click. I can't use `cmd+q` become that will quit all my terminals. Do you have a workaround? thanks a lot.

Comment: @sgon00- Set the Terminal.app >Preference >Shell >When the shell exits: to Close if the shell exits cleany

Comment: Thank you very much! This gave me a big headache! Finally, I can `exit` to close the shell. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You can get something close by using the "New command" entry from the File menu (also accessible through <kbd>Shift-Cmd-N</kbd>) to run `vim` in a dedicated tab/window.

You could also just run the GUI version of MacVim.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply. MacVim has many problems to me. I just gave it up. And I want to write this into a script, so it's better I can do it in a command line with some arguments..

Comment: @sgon00 If scriptability is a requirement you probably should add this to the question.